# Robocopy ignore *.so.*

Tags: windows, robocopy

The following command does not work:
`robocopy source target /MIR /XD <dir list> /XF  *.so *.so.*`

Robocopy still tries to copy libs like `the_lib.so.3.2.1`
The directory struct is:
lib/*.so (several files)

lib/*.so.* (several files)
dir1/manyFiles
dir2/moreFiles

source is a remote directory mounted as a network drive
target is a local dir

There is no error on the command arguments as per the command display: all the parameters are passed correctly (including exept *.so.* and *.so). I cannot show the details for privacy issues.

Is it expected? Is there any workaround?

Comment: This command works correctly on my machine. Post your directory structure and what `<dir list>` is so we can narrow down the issue.

Comment: In my testing; `source > lib1 >> lib1.lib, lib1.pdb, lib1.so, lib1.so.3.2.1 > lib2 >> lib1.lib, lib1.pdb, lib1.so, lib1.so.3.2.1 > dir1 >> manyfiles... > dir2 >> manyfiles...`

Running `robocopy z:\ target /MIR /XD dir* /XF *.so *.so.*` leaves the target directory as; `target > lib1 >> lib1.lib, lib1.pdb > lib2 >> lib1.lib, lib1.pdb``

Which appears to be what you expect. There must be something else in your environment/setup which isn't clear.

Comment: Actually the libs are symbolic links and robocopy tries to copy them for no reason (i sucesfully excluded other symlinks by names without a "*", it looks like '*' does not apply to exclude rules if simlinks ). I solved my issue with /XJ option which in my case is even better

Comment: Nice work. Post that as an answer with some detail and accept so other users can find this more easily in the future.